# How to add html content to another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is supposed to work, but i am not able to figure out the problem. Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GNSpU/2/)

I have an accordion with these menus `HealthCheck`, `Configuration` and `System`
When I click on any one of them according to that particular element `id` `detailTable` div element gets appended (but before remove all elements from `detailTable` div) but in my case even the appending is not getting reflected, what seems to be the problem in my code? Please have a look somebody. Thanks

My code

```
<div id="ds-accordion">
<table cellspacing="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="25%" valign="top" style="padding-right:5px" >
            <div id="mainAccordion" class="Accordion">
                <p class="AccordionPanelTab">&nbsp;<a id="healthCheckAccordion" onClick=""><img align="left" src="/csm/include/images/healthicon.gif">Health Check</a></p>
                <div class="AccordionPanelContent">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                </div>
                <p class="AccordionPanelTab"><a id="configurationAccordion" onClick=""><img align="left" src="/csm/include/images/conficon.gif">Configuration</a></p>
                <div class="AccordionPanelContent" >
                    <!-- 2nd Level -->
                    <div id="main2ndAccordion" class="Accordion" >
                        <p class="AccordionPanelTab">&nbsp;<a id="systemAccordion" onClick="" >System</a></p>
                        <div class="AccordionPanelContent">
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        </div>
                        <p class="AccordionPanelTab"><a id="productAccordion" onClick="" ></a></p>
                        <div class="AccordionPanelContent">
                            <a href="#" >Link 1</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                            
        </td>

        <td width="75%" valign="top" style:"padding-left:10px;">
            <div id="detailTable">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

My JS part

```
$('#ds-accordion a').click(function (event) {
    var elementId = $(this).attr("id");
    treeItemClickHandler(elementId);
});

var idMap = {
    "healthCheckAccordion": healthCheckDisplay,
    "configurationAccordion": configurationDisplay,
    "systemAccordion": systemDisplay
};

function healthCheckDisplay(id) {
    $('<div>').attr('id', 'healthCheckSpan').attr('style', 'display: none;').html('<div class="titleBlue">Health Check Summary</div>' + '<table style="border:#2F5882 1px solid;width:100%;"  cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">' + '<thead>' + '<tr style="color :#FFFFFF;background-color: #8EA4BB">' + '<th width="10%" align="center"><b>Recommendations</b></th>' + '</tr>' + '</thead>' + '<tbody >' + '<tr style="color :#2F5882;background-color: #EDF1F5">' + '<td align="left" width="10%"><span id="recommendations"></span></td>' + '</tr>' + '</tbody>' + '</table>' + '</div>').appendTo('#detailTable');
    $("#detailTable").css("display", "inline");
    alert("healthCheckDisplay " + id);

}

function configurationDisplay(id) {
    alert("configurationDisplay " + id);
}

function systemDisplay(id) {
    alert("systemDisplay " + id);
}

function treeItemClickHandler(id) {
    (idMap[id])(id);
}
```

**Edited** 
solution to 2nd part of the question, removing html element from div

```
$('#detailTable').empty();
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the code in the question itself.

Comment: Wow, you ask a **lot** of questions (not that it's a bad thing... just saying!)

Comment: hey... where do we have a look?

Comment: @Coding Freak: This is the [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/GNSpU/2/)

Comment: @JohnP: I added my code in question also, please take a look

Comment: @Matt: Ya I am a beginner, and kind of daily using some or the other technology.. where my learning most of the time now is diving into code as soon as I have some basic idea of the tech. So please bear with me :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking in your question, but the reason the HTML is not being displayed by the `healthCheckDisplay` function is that this builds a `<div>` with an `id` of `healthCheckSpan`, and a `style` of `display: none`.

Remove the call to `attr` that sets the style and you'll see the appended elements. See http://jsfiddle.net/GNSpU/6/

Comment: OMG how silly of me.. Thanks for mentioning the problem and answering my 1st part of the question. My 2nd part is before adding how do I remove any `html` which have already been appended to `detailTable`?

Comment: @Abhishek: Maybe your real-life problem is different, but in your example you're just appending hard-coded HTML, so wouldn't it be easier to move this out of the Javascript and into the main HTML, then just use jQuery to hide/show the `healthCheckSpan` element?

Comment: I want a dynamic content, coz there are lot of accordion tabs , previously I was hiding and showing contents as needed as you told  (i.e., i did your way before, now refactoring the code as i have been asked to do so).. but that time, my JS code was quite large so may be that is the reason and also some other stuff that i was asked to change a few things. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

To remove elements from a `<div>`, you could utilize `$.remove()`:

```
$('#divToEmpty').children().remove();
```

This won't allow chaining, though, so you might want to consider just using `.html()` instead of `.appendTo()`:

```
// Before:
$('<div>'). ... .appendTo('#detailTable');
// After
$('#detailTable').html($('<div>'). ... );
```

**Update**: As you pointed out in one of your comments to another answer, `.empty()` works too. In order to utilize chaining with `.empty()`, you'll have to do something like this:

```
$('#detailTable').empty().append($('<div'>)...);
// or
$('<div'>). ... .appendTo($('#detailTable').empty()); // not really chained...
```

Comment: I found a solution `$('#detailTable').empty();` is this something different coz id does the work for me.. which 1 should i use?

Comment: @Abhishek: It doesn't matter which one you use - they do the same thing. In fact, if you got empty working, don't change it :P (My main reason to edit it in here was to make it easy to find for then next person who comes here looking for a solution to the same problem...)